# Couldn't match expected type ‘IO ()’ with actual type [Place]

Tags: haskell

Trying to run some haskell code, but it's not running. Gives me the error seen above

```
type Name = String
type Location = (Float,Float)
type RainfallFigures = [Int]
type Place = (Name,Location,RainfallFigures)

testData::[Place]
testData=[("London", (51.5, -0.1), [0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0]),("Cardiff", (51.5 , -3.2),[12, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0, 2])]

rtnNames::[Place] -> [Place]
rtnNames x=x 


demo :: Int -> IO ()
demo 1 = rtnNames testData
```

Error occurs on the last line demo 1 = rtnNames testData
I'm trying to get rtnNames to just return the test data itself for now as a first hurdle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your signature

```
demo :: Int -> IO ()
```

indicates that demo should return an IO action of type `IO ()`. However, your implementation returns `rtnNames testData`. Since the implementation of `rtnNames` just returns its argument, this is equivalent to just `testData`. That's a problem, though, since `testData` is a `[Place]`, not an `IO ()`. Perhaps you want to *print* the list of names? That would look like this:

```
demo 1 = print testData
```

which I expect will compile.

There are, however, some deeper design issues with your code. You're using a number of `type`s that would probably be better as `newtype`s. `newtype` lets you extend the type checker to make sure that a particular `[Int]` is actually a `RainfallFigures`, and not just any old list of numbers.

Your `rtnNames` function is also concerning, since it doesn't do anything. There's nothing intrinsically wrong with a function that does nothing, and in fact it can be quite useful, which is why it exists out of the box, viz. `id` with type `a -> a`. `rtnNames` is just a specialization of `id`, but from the context in which you use it, I suspect it isn't meant to be.

Comment: rtnNames does nothing because I was just trying to get my program past the first hurdle of actually running. But thank you. I replaced rtnNames testData with print (rtnNames testData) and it worked

Comment: Aha! Sure, as a stub, that's fine. Still would encourage you to look into `newtype`s. It's really great to have the compiler statically enforce the _semantic type_ of the data instead of just enforcing the _internal storage type_.